# to which subnet IP address belongs?

Tags: bash, ip, subnet

I have to write a script in bash , perl or python.
I got file with three columns (for manually manage connect-proxy)

```
SUBNET/IP         socks_port        socks_ip 
1.2.3.*              1080             9.8.7.6
1.1.*                1080             6.8.7.6
```

I want to know to which subnet belongs IP address, 
for example:

```
$ my_script  1.1.1.2
```

this IP belongs to `1.1.*` subnet so I want back second line.

Comment: Do you need to support subnets that are not /8, /16, /24, or /32 ?  If so, this x.x.x.* format isn't going to work out for you.  For example, 1.1.1.2/25 and 1.1.1.200/25 are both 1.1.1.*, but are on different networks.

Answer (score 1):

**BASH**: quick and dirty, use `cut`, then `grep` over the file.

**PYTHON**: use `ip.rsplit()` and then `line.split()[].startswith()` iterating through the file.

**PERL**: no idea.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the format given (i.e. using *), it'll be fairly easy to use bash pattern matching to compare this to the ip address.  However, as @Mark Drago pointed out, this format anything except octet-boundary subnets, so if you need to support arbitrary subnet boundaries, you need a better format.

Assuming you are using the "1.2.*" format, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="$1"
found_match=false
while read subnet socks_port socks_ip; do
    if [[ "$ip" == $subnet ]]; then  # this'll do glob-style pattern matching against $subnet
        echo "subnet=$subnet, socks_port=$socks_port, socks_ip=$socks_port"
        found_match=true
        break  # assuming you don't want to check for multiple matches
    fi
done </path/to/subnet/file

if ! $found_match; then
    echo "No match found in subnet file"
fi
```